# How to access a control in one item renderer from another item renderer in Flex 2.0

Tags: apache-flex

How to access a control in one item renderer from another item renderer
For eg. I have a listbox in one itemrenderer of a  datagrid column and I need to access the same in another itemrenderer of another datagrid column.How can i do this?

Comment: This would be a break in encapsulation, leading to less code reuse; so I have strong reservations about accessing one renderer inside another.  If you need to "Share" data across columns in a DataGrid; the data should, theoretically, be part of the data element from your dataProvider.  Otherwise you can use static variables or a singleton approach to share data across multiple components.

Comment: Thanks ! I used a static variable concept to share values.It worked.

Comment: @Coral Doe Please kindly help me in steps to accept an answer as I dont find the checkbox or right symbol for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ! I used a static variable concept to store values of one itemrenderer in another item renderer and updated the values of the same.